# Is there any better way to get email from 3 username at once in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 username, ie: usernameA,usernameB,usernameC. And I have also their email in a table, ie: usernamea@gmail,usernameb@gmail,usernamec@gmail. I don't know how to get these emails at once from that 3 username. I can do it by this:

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT email FROM t_un WHERE username='usernameA'");
$f=mysql_fetch_object($q);
$emailA=$f->email;

$q=mysql_query("SELECT email FROM t_un WHERE username='usernameB'");
$f=mysql_fetch_object($q);
$emailB=$f->email;

$q=mysql_query("SELECT email FROM t_un WHERE username='usernameC'");
$f=mysql_fetch_object($q);
$emailC=$f->email;
```

but that's uncomfortable for me. Is there any better way to get that emails from 3 username at once in SQL? thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the [IN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your need, but try it out:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t_un.email) AS users FROM t_un WHERE username='usernameA' OR username='usernameB' OR username='usernameC';
```

It will return a comma-separated field called users. You may want another separator, then you can try this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t_un.email SEPARATOR ";") AS users FROM .......
```

Comment: Ok, wait, I'll try it.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. How did you know that this is for sending an email? You are jenius man. +1 for you. I'll take this man.

Comment: :D I'm glad I could help.

Comment: please helping me again in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669459/confusing-about-this-cookies-in-redirecting-system)

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

> BEWARE! This is SQL injection vulnerabile. Do NOT use the code samples presented here.

```
$userNames = array("usernameA", "usernameB", "usernameC");
$array2 = "'" .implode("','", $userNames ) . "'"; 

$q=mysql_query("SELECT email FROM t_un WHERE username IN $array2 ");
$f=mysql_fetch_object($q);
$emailC=$f->email;
```

Comment: It's cool David. I like your answer. It's works also. But i prefer choose @gugabguerra's answer. But +1 for you also david.

Comment: please helping me again in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669459/confusing-about-this-cookies-in-redirecting-system)

Comment: Sorry I was out so I couldn't help on time. But there also nice answer exist now

Comment: It is okay David, no problem, thanks for helping me David. Maybe I'll call you next time.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code. It will provide you each email address in three different variables $emailA, $emailB, $emailC as required.

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT email FROM t_un WHERE username='usernameA' OR username='usernameB' OR username='usernameC'");
$chr_ptr = 'A';

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)){
     eval('$email'.$chr_ptr.' = '.'$row[\'email\'];');
      $chr_ptr++;    
}

echo $emailA;print PHP_EOL;
echo $emailB;print PHP_EOL;
echo $emailC;print PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: I am assuming that it return emails in order with username

Comment: $emailA and $emailB ? are two variables printed

Comment: Sorry Issue was due to mysql_fetch_object which I forget to remove. Please check now.

Comment: It works now man, but sorry I'm a little bit confused to your code (because I'm new in PHP), but it works then. Thank you. But I prefer choose gugabguerra's answer, sorry, but don't worry, i give you +1 also.

Comment: please helping me again in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669459/confusing-about-this-cookies-in-redirecting-system)